# Error al cargar un archvhivo .csv en Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, csv, macos, jupyter

Estoy intentando cargar desde una computadora *Mac* un archivo *csv* en *Jupyter Notebooks* y al hacerlo no reconoce la ruta del archivo.

Lo he intentando reconociendo la ruta con *pwd* pero aún así me sale el mismo error con *Users/Home/data/goog.csv*

> ````
> call last)
>
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File Desktop/data/goog.csv does not
> exist: 'Desktop/data/goog.csv' ```
> ````

Comment: Como el error dice: no encuentra tu archivo. Te recomiendo ubicar el archivo en el mismo directorio que jupyter notebook esta corriendo y lugo leerlo con pd.read_csv(<nombre_del_archivo_str>)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución. El problema es que no permitía indexar el archivo con nombre google. Lo cambié a test y funcionó.

Habría que tener especial atención en los nombres de los archivos.

Gracias